# localStorage no funciona en dominio/hosting

Tags: php, html5, checkbox

pues ha llegado el momento de probar el programita en mi pagina web, el detalle que el localStorage no funciona, activo y desactivo el checkbox, pero el get y el set funcionan y no funcionan, probé unos parámetros que encontré pero no hubo cambio, en mi PC de pruebas con phpmyadmin y localhost no tengo ningún problema.

```
<td><label class='pure-material-checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='box-".$fila['id']."' onclick='clicked(this);'><span></span></label></td>


let chkStat = [];
    function clicked(box) {
        let boxData = {'id': box.id, 'checked': box.checked};
        chkStat.push(boxData);
        localStorage.setItem('chkStat', JSON.stringify(chkStat), 'localKey', 'localValue');
        box.disabled = true;
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        chkStat = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chkStat', 'localKey')) || [];
        chkStat.forEach(item => {
            let check = document.querySelector(`#${item.id}`);
            check.checked = item.checked;
            check.disabled = true;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Creo que estás pasando demasiados argumentos a [`getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) y [`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

Comment: ¿Ves algún error en la consola?

Comment: @juanrpozo localKey y localValue los agregue despues, pero ni con ellos ni sin funciona

Comment: @Triby no, no me marca nada

Comment: @Triby ahorita probé y funciono, pero volví a probar y de nuevo nada, ahí algo por ahí que falla, no se si tarda en accesar al localStorage

Comment: @Triby ¿sabes si el PATH afectaría al localStorage?, hice mas pruebas y todavía mas rara esta la cosa

Comment: Hasta donde sé, localStorage almacena por dominio y no involucra rutas y, de hecho, nunca lo he usado en producción, solo para algunas pruebas.

Comment: @Triby te cuento, hasta hoy no funciona el checkbox, probé con un botón y ya trabaja, lo curioso es que al boton le puse un estilo y el localStorage falla, probare mas tarde con el checkbox a ver si es eso, tampoco he podido con la base de datos, ayudame estimado

Comment: Eso está muy raro, seguramente tienes un conflicto en tu javascript, porque ni el tipo de campo ni los estilos deberían interferir.